# Datacontract or Client Model?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, bdd, datacontract

i am currently writting a Mid/Large silverlight application.

My current architecture is as follows.

On the server side i have entity objects that are created from an exisiting database using the entity framework ORM.

I have WCF Services whos methods pass back Datacontracts that represent my entity objects to the Client silverlight application.

My question is upon recieving the Datacontract on the silverlight side should i 
1) use this DataContract as my Model in MVVM 
2) convert the datacontract into a Client side model object to use in MVVM.

option 1 : I'm not sure if its considered generally bad practice to think of Datacontracts on the client side as models since they are ultimatley WCF Message types.

option 2 : This opotion keeps me completley decoupled from the server and allows me to develop my code from a Behaviour Driven approach.

Comment: Have you considered using WCF RIA Services which was built with Silverlight in mind? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: Yes but unfortunatley the decision has been made not to use Ria since these services are only available to Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in your assessment, the data contracts used for WCF can be thought of as data transfer objects that are a means of transferring data to and from the service.

Your models on the other hand are likely to contain behavior, business rules, and validation. So I would go with option 2.

This will also allow you to manage changes in the service and in the client application more easily, as the service won't be coupled with a particular consumer of the service.